# How to delete all text file from a directory accept one through batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to delete the all the text file from a directory accept one text file.That directory contains other file along with text file. For Example In directory there are 4 different file:

```
D:\
a.txt   b.txt   test.c    test1.cpp
```

I want to delete all the text file accept a.txt,Hence directory contain following file:

```
a.txt     test.c     test1.cpp
```

Consider that a.txt will always available in that directory but not other files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following will remove all `*.TXT` files in current directory except `A.TXT`:

```
FOR %%t IN (*.TXT) DO IF /I NOT "%%~nt" == "a" DEL "%%t"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following:

1. Create a temp directory
2. Move the file you want to keep to the temp dir
3. Delete the rest.
4. Move the file back from the temp directory
5. Remove the temp directory

The below is from memory - you will have to check syntax as I have no way to test it at the moment:

```
mkdir .\temp
copy a.txt .\temp
del *.txt
move .\temp\a.txt .\
rmdir temp
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work too:

```
@echo off
attrib +h a.txt
del *.txt
attrib -h a.txt
```

and also

```
@echo off
ren a.txt a.___
del *.txt
ren a.___ a.txt
```