# Batch delete all files and directories except specified file and directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to delete all files and directories in a specific directory using a bat file in said directory. I've seen this done on Linux without problem, but in Windows command environment it seems to be a chore.

Example: \temp\1.bat (keep) \temp\special folder (keep)

Inside \temp\ contains all the folders and files I want to delete except the 1.bat and the special folder.

I have tried recursive commands but they delete the directory, or they delete all the files and keep the directories.

Example:

```
attrib +r "special directory"
attrib +r "1.bat"
erase /Q *.*
rd /s /q
attrib -r "1.bat"
```

But this remove everything. If I remove the `rd` line, it removes all the files, not the directories and keeps the 1.bat file (like I need).

I've also tried:

```
for /d %%i in (".\*") do if /i not "%%i"=="special folder" rd /s /q "%%i"
```

But this doesn't work either. I simply cannot get all the directories and files to be deleted except for the "special folder" and the "1.bat file".

Is this even possible?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45678627) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21048546) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23644867) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56540744) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20567726) post...

Comment: I tried those all before posting.

Comment: Take a particular look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56544453), which is the most flexible variant since you can specify exceptions by path or name, and for files (`/XF`) you can even use wildcards; do not forget to exclude the batch script itself when it is placed inside of the the target directory tree...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "keepfile=1.bat"
SET "keepdir=keep me"

FOR /d %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*") DO IF /i NOT "%%~nxa"=="%keepdir%" RD /S /Q "%%a"
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*") DO IF /i NOT "%%~nxa"=="%keepfile%" DEL "%%a"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir`, `keepdir` and `keepfile` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

The `for/d` command deals with all of the directories, except that where the name+extension matches the required name, then the `for` repeats the action on files in the target directory, deleteing all except that which matches the required filename-to-keep.

Comment: Getting error %%a was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @Sahin This needs to be run as a batch file, not entered at the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The following batch file could be used for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "TargetFolder=%~1"
if not defined TargetFolder set "TargetFolder=."
set "ExcludeBatchFile="
for %%I in ("%TargetFolder%\") do if "%%~dpI" == "%~dp0" set "ExcludeBatchFile=/C:"%~nx0""
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%TargetFolder%\" /AD /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X /C:"special folder"') do rd /S /Q "%TargetFolder%\%%I"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%TargetFolder%\" /A-D /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X /C:"1.bat" %ExcludeBatchFile%') do del /A /F "%TargetFolder%\%%I"
endlocal
```

`for /F` with `dir` is used instead of `for /D` to process also subdirectories with hidden attribute set. `for /D` ignores subdirectories with hidden attribute.

This batch file runs the directory cleanup on the directory passed as argument to the batch file. It makes the cleanup on current directory if batch file is started without any argument.

The batch file protects itself on being deleted on deleting files in current directory or in a specified target directory and batch file is in current directory or the specified target directory. But the batch file does not protect itself on being deleted if the batch file is stored in any subdirectory of the current directory or specified target directory.

There can be multiple `/C:"Directory Name"` arguments specified on second **FOR** command line to exclude multiple subfolders in target folder for being removed by the batch file.

There can be multiple `/C:"File Name"` arguments specified on third **FOR** command line to exclude multiple files in target folder for being removed by the batch file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `rd /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on both **FOR** command lines to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes these command lines before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with `dir` and `findstr` with using a separate command process started in background using `%ComSpec% /c` and the specified command line.