# cmd.exe for loop: how to delete files with white space in filename

Tags: loops, file, for-loop, cmd

I am trying to write a Windows batch script that should delete any file but .zip in a folder, however the command that I use does not work for files that have white spaces in their filename and I cannot find how to fix it:

```
for /f %%F in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /vile ".zip"') do del "%%F"
```

I have tried with various options of the command but did not work

Comment: The command line to use is: `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%G in ('dir /A-D /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /L /V ".zip"') do del /A /F "%%G"` to delete all files __except__ `.zip` files, even those containing a space in file name or having a file name beginning with a semicolon or having the hidden or the read-only attribute set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch delete all files and directories except specified file and directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57108602/batch-delete-all-files-and-directories-except-specified-file-and-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is explained well here: https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

The relevant part says:

> By default, /F breaks up each line within the file at each blank space
> " ", and any blank lines are skipped, this default parsing behavior
> can be changed by applying one or more of the "options" parameters.
> The option(s) must be contained "within quotes"

The way to do that in your case is to tell `for` that it should not consider spaces as delimiters, in fact you don't want any delimiters:

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /vile ".zip"') do echo "%%F"
```

(I changed the command to `echo`, since I don't want careless people accidentally deleting files because you or I made a mistake :) - once you convinced yourself it's good, change it back to `del`)

Edit: updated to include quotes in command, as indicated in comments.

Comment: Thank you it works! Just one note, when using the DEL  %%F the argument should be placed within double quotes otherwise files with spaces in their filename won't be deleted: for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /vile ".zip"') do DEL "%%F"